# Problem with uploading SQLiteStudio database to pgAdmin 4 Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a problem after loading database to pgAdmin 4. Maybe anyone have a solution? Thank in advance!

I think its syntax problem but i am not sure.

```
Error: ERROR: BŁĄD: błąd składni w lub blisko "#" LINE 6: #PRAGMA foreign_keys = off; ^

SQL state: 42601 Character: 121
```

My database starts:

```
#PRAGMA foreign_keys = off; #BEGIN TRANSACTION;

-- Tabela: inputs CREATE TABLE inputs (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE NOT NULL, name TEXT, inputid INT, connectionid INT, type INT, posx DOUBLE, posy DOUBLE); INSERT INTO inputs (id, name, inputid, connectionid, type, posx, posy) VALUES (42, 'Unknown', 1, 23, 0, 276.0, 226.316); INSERT INTO inputs (id, name, inputid, connectionid, type, posx, posy) VALUES (43, 'WEJ', 1, 51, 4, 726.159, 384.892);
```

Comment: `#pragma ...` is invalid in Postgres (and standard SQL). If that is supposed to be a comment: in SQL, comments are [introduced](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-COMMENTS) with a `--` at the start of the line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted PRAGMA . as @a_horse_with_no_name says it was invalid.
also I was need to convert all my database from SQlite to Postgres.